# ImageView Using findViewById from another XML file

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to create findViewbyId of an imageview that belongs to another xml file in onCreate method. Before knowing this,

I used this code which gives me the nullpointerexception error because my imageview is in another xml file.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //init image
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_image);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        image = drawable.getBitmap();
```

I want to use this imageView which is in main_fragment.xml layout

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
```

How should I call my imageView inside onCreate ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_image);
```

replace with

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Instantiate `image` as `Bitmap` first

Comment: thanks but im currently trying to solve for my imageView.  i want to be able use imageView in (main_fragment.xml) when my onCreate is set to another layout      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); . Do you have any idea?